# Google Prediction API is giving opposite data?

Tags: api

professor from Georgia state institute here. 
I've recently tried using the renowned Google Prediction API, however with a slight problem.

I'm creating a Sentimental Analysis model

"positive","good"
"positive","legend"
"negative","worst"
"negative","terrible"

The problem is that when I run a Google prediction query, for say "good" I receive "negative" when I know for a fact it should be "good" since it's marked with the "positive" label.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your trainmodel work well,and make sure the trainmodel was created successfully.
you use [prediction.trainedmodels.get] to check the trainedmodels resource.